# Getting filters from manually entered URL and fetching data accordingly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a page that by default gets all data with no `filters`. I have a `filters` state to hold the filters. now the issue is if someone enters the filters manually in the browser, since the page loads up again, i get all the data even though there are filters in url. i checked `filters` are actually there and i have them in `filters` state but the data is fetched and `loaded` is set to `true`

so it renders the data that was received upon page load. here is the code

I get the query string `seacrhFor` like this on the very top

`const _searchFor=new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("searchFor");`

```
const [filters,filtersSetter]=useState();

const[loaded,loadedSetter]=useState(false)
const [dataHolder,dataSetter]=useState();

const getData=async function (filterParams) {
    let apiUrl="api/Profiles/AllProfiles"+filtersParams;
    
    loadedSetter(false); // data is not loaded yet
    var res=(await axios.get(apiUrl)).data;
    
    dataSetter(res.data); //data is put into an state
    loadedSetter(true); //data is loaded, component can render now
    return;


        
}

useEffect(() => {
    loadedSetter(false);
    filtersSetter({
        searchFor:_searchFor,
    })
}, [])
useEffect(() => {
    // This gets called when state is set to null at first, then right away its 
    //called with filters values but its late already and the data is presented
    getData(filters); //calls the function that gets the data
    history.push(filters)//for url purposes
    
}, [filters])
```

I could add a new state to prevent it from rendering unless the filters values are ready to be passed, but thats way too many states. is there another thing i can do?
Also with this current code, if I keep entering the URL and the API responds a bit faster I'm able to see the filtered data, that's how I figured what the issue is. there is no issues if filters are set after page load by user in the web app.

Comment: Why not initialize the state with the URL params? `const [filters, setFilters] = useState({ searchFor: new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('searchFor') });` That way you avoid the state update in the first `useEffect` hook which causes the behavior you observe.

Comment: As a next step, you could make use of a dedicated hook like `useQueryParam` from https://github.com/pbeshai/use-query-params or similar

Comment: @digitalbreed i can't believe i didnt think of that in the first place. Thanks i figured it out